# How to separate csv array by column?

Tags: php, arrays, csv, foreach

I have a giant list in excel, they are just two columns

```
name    type
```

The file is currently being read:

```
$lines = array_map('str_getcsv', file('file.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
```

`print_r($lines);` returns:

```
   name1;type
   name2;type2
   ...

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => name1;type1) [1] => Array ( [0] => name2;type2)...
```

I would like to access separate name and type in an foreach

How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[str_getcsv](http://php.net/str_getcsv) default delimiter is ',' so you need call it somehow with explicitly specifying ';' as delimeter

for example like this

```
$myGetCsv = function ($str) {
    return str_getcsv($str, ';');
};

$lines = array_map($myGetCsv, file('file.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for CSV file reading. it ease to use and understand how its work.

```
if (($handle = fopen('./suppression_invalid_emails.csv', "r")) !== false) {
     //getting column name
     $column_headers = fgetcsv($handle);
     foreach ($column_headers as $header) {
        //column as array;
          $result[$header] = array();
     }
     // get data for column;
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
          $i = 0;
          foreach ($result as &$column) {
               $column[] = $data[$i++];
          }
     }
     fclose($handle);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); echo '</pre>';
}
```

i use two basic function for this 1st one is [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for reading file and other is [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) for getting data for column.

and result is:

```
Array
(
    [reason] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mail domain mentioned in email address is unknown
            [1] => Known bad domain
            [2] => Known bad domain
        )

    [email] => Array
        (
            [0] => muneque@collegeclub.om
            [1] => saharfa2000@hatmail.com
            [2] => tawheeda81@yahoo.co
        )

    [created] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1502644294
            [1] => 1502480171
            [2] => 1502344320
        )

)
```